# How to make post button to a random post

Tags: posts, loop, order

As you can see on my website http://www.kieshetsnel.nl/emma-watson-natalie-portman/ I currently have an Arrow left and right on the screen. But when i click next post (volgende keuze in Dutch) I Always have the same order.

Is it possible to make these 'next post' go to a random post (www.kieshetsnel.nl/random/) and Always be a loop, so there is no end on clicking that Arrow. Also an option that on a category page it selects a post from the current category?

The arrows are now part of the plugin WP Post Navigation, but when i have a code for something similar like this the plugin can be removed ofcourse.

Regards,

Comment: Then why don't you hard code it to `http://www.kieshetsnel.nl/random/`?

Comment: Sorry I really don't know anything about coding yet but planning it to learn it in the next couple of months. Can you tell me some mlfe how to hardcode it and what do I have to do? @robert

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress for get random post you have a option with  'orderby' => 'rand'

Comment: Sorry about the question I still got and thanks for the answer in advance. But where can I find that exactly? And does it work with that plugin in that case? Or by coding itself?